# Restart systemd .service with .timer unit

Tags: systemd, services, systemd-timer, systemd-unit

I have the following systemd myscript.service unit that executes an script:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyScript
Wants=time-sync.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/test.sh -a
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/test.sh -b

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I want to restart it each minute with the following  Systemd myscript.timer unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Schedule script execution

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/1

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

It only works the first time, after it, the status remains in n/a:

```
# systemctl list-timers
NEXT                         LEFT        LAST                         PASSED      UNIT                         ACTIVATES
n/a                          n/a         Tue 2019-10-15 14:50:01 EDT  3ms ago     myscript.timer               myscript.service
```

~

Answer (score 5):

If a .service unit will be executed from a .timer unit, it can't have `RemainAfterExit=true`. The [systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) mentions that:

> Note that in case the unit to activate is already active at the time
>   the timer elapses it is not restarted, but simply left running. There
>   is no concept of spawning new service instances in this case. Due to
>   this, services with RemainAfterExit= set (which stay around
>   continuously even after the service's main process exited) are usually
>   not suitable for activation via repetitive timers, as they will only
>   be activated once, and then stay around forever.

So, remove `RemainAfterExit=true` and it will work.

Comment: BTW: You should be able to say `OnCalendar=minutely`, which is a bit clearer. Also you might want to mention `AccuracySec` (though the default one minute should be fine here).